# Testing whether process that generates coins is biased

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_k$ be the number of heads observed when tossing coin $k$ $n_k$ times. Each coin has it's own independent heads probability $p_k$:

$$
X_k \sim \text{Binomial}(n_k, p_k)
$$

Each $p_k$ is drawn from some distribution $P$. I am interested in conducting a hypothesis test to test whether $P$ has mean $\frac{1}{2}$.  Is there an appropriate testing framework to use?

Does the choice of $P$ matter (a lot?). $P$ will be a reasonably nice distribution (eg continuous, unimodal).

I know this question may not be fully precisely stated - the question is motivated by the design of a biological experiment. Any ideas or references would be appreciated.

---

Let's take $P$ to be distributed as $G/(G+H)$ where $G$ and $H$ are iid Poisson with parameter $\lambda_k$. I'd be interested in the answer with $\lambda \in [10,100]$. This may be intractable. I'd also be interested in the answer with a more simple $P$, say the hat distribution on $[a,1−a]$. It would be great if there was an (approximate) answer that depends only on the moments of $P$.

> The spirit of the question is really to understand the relationship between $n$ and $k$. In order to have a powerful test, should I flip more coins, or should I flip each coin more often?

Comment: Yes, the choice of $P$ matters, and to get a precise answer, the question needs to be more precisely stated.

Comment: Let's take P to be distributed as $G / (G + H)$ where $G$ and $H$ are iid Poisson with parameter $\lambda_k$. I'd be interested in the answer with $\lambda \in [10, 100]$. This may be intractable. I'd also be interested in the answer with a more simple $P$, say the hat distribution on $[a, 1-a]$. It would be great if there was an (approximate) answer that depends only on the moments of $P$. The spirit of the question is really to understand the relationship between $n$ and $k$. Ie, in order to have a powerful test, should I flip more coins, or should I flip each coin more often.

Answer (score 1):

You could structure this as a Bayesian hierarchical model and analyze
the posterior distribution of $ P $ conditioned on your "populations" which
are the coin toss outcomes under each $ p_k $. This is, of course, just one example.

The precise distribution of $ P $ will definitely depend on your choice
of prior on $ P $, but at the end of the day you can always numerically
approximate the posterior distribution of $ P $.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestion. I agree that this is a reasonable approach. At the moment I'm most interested in a frequentist hypothesis test. This is because the design I've discussed is an alternative to another design which is well studied in the frequentist framework - and I'd like to be able to compare them